# I want to write a function which is remove multiple consecutive spaces from the array in java

Tags: java, trim

I want to write a  trim() function that will take an array of characters as an input and remove multiple consecutive spaces from the array.Here's my Code:

```
public class Trim {

    public static char [] trim(char [] input) {
    int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] != ' ')
            {
                input[j++] = input[i];
            }

            if (i == input.length - 1)
            {
                while (j < input.length)
                {
                    input[j] ='\0';
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }

        return input;
    }
```

This is my tester file

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    char [] input = {'T','h','i','s',' ',' ',' ',' ','i','s'};

    for (int i = 0; i< input.length; i++){
      System.out.print(input[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("");
    char []  output = trim(input);

    for (int i = 0; i< output.length; i++){
        System.out.print(output[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("");    
    }
}
```

expected output:

```
This me
```

My output shows

```
Thisme
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the replace function - `input.replaceAll(" +", " ");`

Comment: Sine you are returning the trimmed array, I suppose you don't want to mess with the original. In that case you shouldn't change it in your function but rather create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example which modifies the original array. The ideia is to have `i` always on the next char and to stall `j` whenever both of the them are whitespaces. In other words, advance `j` when either of them is non-withespace:

```
public static void trim(char[] input)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        if (input[j] != ' ' || input[i] != ' ')
        {
            j++;
        }
        input[j] = input[i];
    }
    input = Arrays.copyOf(input, j + 1);
}
```

Comment: 2 error . First it does not return anything . 2nd How do java convert void to char ?

Comment: It's what I already explained in the comments. Just like you, I am changing the original array. The array you pass as parameter gets modified by the function. No need to return.
Only if you don't want to change the original array, you need to create a new one and return it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an working example:

```
public static char [] trim(char [] input){
  //Your code here
  char [] output =  new char[input.length];      
  int i=0;
  int count=0;
  for( int j =0; j< input.length; j++ )
  {           
     if ( input[j]!= ' ')
     {
        count=0;
        output[i] = input[j] ;
        i++;           
     }
     else {
        count++; 
     } //System.out.println( '\0');
     if( count==1)
     {
       output[i]= ' ';
       i++;
     }
  }
  return output;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You are skipping over every single space character.

Doing something like this instead:

```
if ((lastchar== ' ')

{
if ((lastchar== ' ') && (nextchar==' ')
{
 ;}

// this will use the final ' ' as a char but ignore all previous!
```

Comment: Working example would be better